# Best way to fill numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
 a = []
 for j in range(1000):
     a.append(sample_function(x))
 a = np.array(a)
```

What is the proper and elegant way to replace this code?
I don't work working with python list is optimal.

Comment: Isn't your `x` supposed to be `j`?

Comment: If your question did not get true answer yet, you must prepare an example (which contain the function too) and expected result.

Comment: you can't improve on this if `somefunction` has to be run 1000 times.

Comment: We cannot provide much help as long a `sample_function` is unspecified - as to what it produces (scalar, array, something else?), and how it might depend on the iteration variable, `j`.

Comment: An alternative is to create `a=np.empty(1000)`, and do `a[j] = sample_function(x)` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume `sample_function(x)` is a scaler, you can use:

```
a = np.full(shape=1000, sample_function(x))  # or smth like --> np.full((1, 1000), sample_function(x))
```

but if you have an array that you would to apply a function on all of the elements:

```
a = np.apply_along_axis(sample_function, axis, arr)  # or --> np.apply_over_axes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
a = example_function(np.arange(1000))
```

where `example_function` is arbitrary, i.e.:

```
def example_function(x):
    return x**2
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create a numpy array using values from a function.

You could try using np.fromfunction like this:

```py
import random  # for example sample function

def sample_function(_):
    return random.random() * 42

a = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(sample_function), (1000, ))
```

If you want `sample_function` to calculate values depending on the coordinates then this is also straight forward:

```
def sample_function(i):
    return random.random() * i
```

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
a=np.arange(0,1000,1)
```

Comment: Im familiar with this syntax. Sorry my question wasn't clear,  I would like to store some given special values in the numpy array.

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.